# Reads a series of lines Python

Tags: python-3.x

Can someone enlighten me how to do this?

Write a Python program that reads a series of lines one by one from the keyboard (ending by an empty line) and, at the end, outputs the number of times that the first line occurred. For example, if it reads

hello
world
We say hello
hello
Birkbeck
hello

it would output 3 since the first line ("hello") occurred three times.

You may assume that the user enters at least two non-empty lines before the empty line.

Comment: Inside a while loop you collect standard input data, then you compute occurence and store it in a variable that you print when you exit the loop !

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you haven't yet, you need to make an honest attempt at solving the problem yourself before asking here. If you've tried something already that didn't work, share that as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and ask a specific question about the problem you ran into.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you want to separate word with spaces or with the newline character and if we count the first occurence.

This is a sample solution for spaces separation between words. This works for the example that you provided

```
freq_dict = {}

word = input().split()
for w in word:
    if w not in freq_dict.keys():
        freq_dict[w] = 0
    else:
        freq_dict[w] += 1

print(freq_dict[word[0]])
```